# How can I detect a date from the content of a file using %F bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have some files that have date inside and I want to check if the content of the file is more current. I can check for comparison of dates but I cannot grep date from the file. for example in file1 i have:

```
my name is Adelaide in Lagos 9:29AM (Author)}||2015-03-13 13:12:59.239308|2012-07-09 10:00:00|reading|3110311|off the internet |3012364|3012364|3012364|63613191| SectionStart
```

file2 has:

```
63615595| Summary|Final|New Roman; Name if here for  earsProvider: ||2015-03-13 13:12:59.239308| Summary 2012-07-09 09:00:00|2210299|3110311|2824032|O6550610|63615595|
```

Since they are not in conformity of table and a file can have more than one date format in it, I only want to retrieve the dates with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: this is just a free text file. is there anyway I can check for date in the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep to get your timestamps:

```
grep -oP '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](?=\|)' file
```